# How to add child fragment inside parent fragment android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

I have main layout. I want to add fragment in main LinearLayout. But if I want to add child fragment in main fragment, it is currently present and visible.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

In Fragment activity, I added this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

HomeFragment homeFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
homeFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.linearlayout_fragment, homeFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Now I want to add child fragment in current home fragment:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

RepairFragment repairFragment = RepairFragment.newInstance();
repairFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.linearlayout_fragment, repairFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

But I got Exception:

```
04-15 11:18:26.394: E/AndroidRuntime(12561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 11:18:26.394: E/AndroidRuntime(12561): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f070005 (com.test.simple:id/linearlayout_fragment) for fragment RepairFragment{42319fb0 #0 id=0x7f070005}
04-15 11:18:26.394: E/AndroidRuntime(12561):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
04-15 11:18:26.394: E/AndroidRuntime(12561):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
04-15 11:18:26.394: E/AndroidRuntime(12561):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-15 11:18:26.394: E/AndroidRuntime(12561):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
04-15 11:18:26.394: E/AndroidRuntime(12561):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
04-15 11:18:26.394: E/AndroidRuntime(12561):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-15 11:18:26.394: E/AndroidRuntime(12561):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-15 11:18:26.394: E/AndroidRuntime(12561):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
04-15 11:18:26.394: E/AndroidRuntime(12561):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
04-15 11:18:26.394: E/AndroidRuntime(12561):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 11:18:26.394: E/AndroidRuntime(12561):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-15 11:18:26.394: E/AndroidRuntime(12561):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
04-15 11:18:26.394: E/AndroidRuntime(12561):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
04-15 11:18:26.394: E/AndroidRuntime(12561):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(getParentFragment().getId(), repairFragment);
fragmentTransaction.replace(getView().getId(), repairFragment);
```

Comment: so you want fragment into fragment into fragmentactivity?

Comment: no. fragment in fragment which is in fragmentActivity

Answer (score -1):

so try another xml

```
       <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout_fragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_below="@id/header" >

        </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved . Just assigned id to parent fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout_repair_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_repair"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="repair" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_repair_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="repair 1 " />

</LinearLayout>
```

and

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.linearlayout_repair_fragment, repairFragment);
```